# Dirichlet characters

Tags: number-theory

In the book

Congruences for L-Functions by  Urbanowicz, J. and Williams, Kenneth S.

in page 28 the authors state that for odd character $\chi$ modulo $M$ the sum

$$M^{-1}\sum_{a=1}^M\chi (a)a$$

after some manipulation can be rewritten as

$$\frac{1}{\bar{\chi}(2)-2}\sum_{1\leq a\leq M/2}\chi(a)$$

I can not prove it. Someone can help me?

Comment: What have you done? Did you check it for an odd character?